# Realm android, delete object and update while keeping model

Tags: java, android, mvvm, binding, realm

I started to work in a project who was started yet. It has been developed with the Mvvm patron and uses Realm for data storage.
We use same Realm objects as data for the viewmodel in different screens without recreate the fragments.

The problem comes with the updates.

Currently the app asks for new data, and when receive executes deleteObjectsAndAttribs for clean the current data and copyToRealmOrUpdate to add the new data.

This is actually working well when moving to new screens with different data, but if I keep in same screen or go back to a screen that uses same model, the object becomes invalidated.

Any work arround?

Comment: Requery data in `onStart`

Comment: The problem is that all the screens are fragments and in order to create a navigation similar to iOS (customer wants it) we are using addToBackStack instead of replace, so the we are not recreating the fragment, also it something the model becomes invalid in the same fragment without navigation.

Comment: I can't answer this without seeing code, but probably registering a RealmChangeListener on a RealmResults would yield the right results (no pun intended)

Comment: Well actually what seems to work ok is, on model load I make a copy with copyFromRealm, since that, every time I used to call the model, I call a function who checks if model is valid, if not returns the copy.